# Rails asset pipeline and byte serving HTML5 video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, html5-video

HTML5 video served via the rails asset pipeline (e.g. placed in `/app/assets/videos`) isn't responding with the status code **206 Partial Content**.

The video does show correctly but responds with **200 OK** instead, making seeking (and looping, I believe) impossible.

The same video served as a static file placed within the `/public` folder does in fact return with **206 Partial Content** as desired.

I can rule out it's an encoding issue and the test video in question is one from videojs' site: http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4

For a particular project we've been asked to place video within the `/app/assets/videos` folder, but the above is forcing us to place the video elsewhere (e.g. within `/public` or elsewhere on the web) and as such, out of the source repository.

Putting aside the question of whether video should be committed to source or not, does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dig into the rails source, you'll see that requests to assets (that aren't in /public) are served via [sprockets-rails](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L132) which mounts a rack app that is an instance of `Sprockets::Environment` on the /assets path.

If you then dig into sprockets, the rack bit of it is implmented by [`Sprockets::Server`](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/server.rb). If you read through that it's pretty clear that this doesn't support partial gets - nothing ever checks for a Range header. I don't think this is for any reason other than no-one has needed it enough to implement it.

On the other hand when a file is in public, it's either served by [`Rack::File`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/file.rb#L81), which does support partial gets or by whatever server you've put in front of it (nginx, apache) which will typically support partial gets.